# My new anchor tag is not working in .tpl file

Tags: php, html

I am trying to modify a template which consists of `.tpl` files instead of `.html` or `.php`. There are some anchor tags like this:

```
<a href="{$vurl}?p=about" class="someclass">About Us</a>
```

but if I try to point to a different page in anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="{$vurl}?p=newAboutUs" class="someclass">About Us</a>
```

it is not working. I have already created "newAboutUs.tpl" and copied "about.tpl" content and pasted to "newAboutUs.tpl".

But when I click the "About Us" button, nothing is happening.

If I put everything back and try to click the button it is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your controller file you have assigned $vurl or not.

Comment: Thanks Vijay. 
I have found there are some .php files. I think i have to assigned a new .php files to new pages.